# Ie9 Html5 audio tag in jbosserver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, internet-explorer-9

I am using audio tag in html5 page. It is working fine in all the browsers except Ie9.

The code is :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Add a title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <audio controls="controls" src="audio-file.mp3" autoplay>
       audio tag not supported.
    </audio>         
    </body>
    </html>
```

If i open directly the html page it is working fine, but same page is failed to load when trying to open in server(jbosserver).

Regards
Chandrasekhar M

Comment: Have you added `<!DOCTYPE html>` to your html page?

Comment: Press F12, and look at which Document Mode is being used.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Add a title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <audio controls="controls" src="audio-file.mp3" autoplay>
       audio tag not supported.
    </audio>         
    </body>
    </html>